# Cleaning divided roads on a graph to count intersections within x distance accurately

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I'm trying to count the amount of intersections within x distance of each edge of a graph to then display using a colour ramp, however divided roads show up as multiple intersections instead of just one.

The script below shows my current working using osmnx to create the graph, then networkx shortest path to find paths across all nodes. Returning the count that are within x distance and then an average of the nodes for the edges.

I know that osmnx has the clean intersections function but that doesn't integrate with the existing graph.

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

location = 'location'
distance = x
net_type = 'drive'

G = ox.graph_from_place(location, buffer_dist=distance, network_type=net_type)
G = ox.project_graph(G)

shortest = nx.shortest_path_length(G, weight='length')

count_list = []
for node in list(shortest):
    int_count = 0
    for key in node[1]:
        if node[1].get(key) <= 400:
            int_count += 1
        else:
            break
    count_list.append(int_count)

intersections = dict(zip(G.nodes, count_list))

nx.set_node_attributes(G, intersections, 'int400')

nodes = list(G.nodes)
data_nodes = list(G.nodes(data=True))
for edge in G.edges(data=True):
    node_from = data_nodes[nodes.index(edge[0])][1]['int']
    node_to = data_nodes[nodes.index(edge[1])][1]['int']
    average = round(((node_from + node_to) / 2))
    edge[2]['int'] = average
```

I would like it so that it only counts a single intersection where roads intersect divided roads.

I'm quite new to using these so some of the above code could be done in a different way as well. But my primary focus is on getting an accurate intersection count for each node/edge in the graph.

Is there a way to use the osmnx clean intersections function and integrate that with the existing graph, adjusting the from/to attributes of the edges to the new nodes?

I was thinking you might be able to identify which nodes are removed and then replace any instance of that id with a new node id that replaced it, but I don't know if that is possible.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use the osmnx clean intersections function and integrate that with the existing graph, adjusting the from/to attributes of the edges to the new nodes?

There's currently a pull request open to add this functionality: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/pull/249

In general at this point, you'd want to create a projected copy of your graph, clean the intersections to within some meter tolerance, then count intersections on that graph.

Comment: Thanks Geoff.

I'll keep an eye on that and test it when I get a chance.